# What is the package and background process for "network time"?

Tags: gnome, time, date, ntp

What is the background process of "network time" in gnome control center (gnome system settings)? Is there a package providing this feature?

I've noticed that neither ntp nor openntpd are installed in Ubuntu 12.10

[image: ubuntu 12.10 date and time network time]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time a network connection is established, the script `/etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate` runs and ultimately calls `ntpdate-debian`, which sets the clock from the servers listed in the `NTPSERVERS` variable defined in `/etc/default/ntpdate`.

Answer (score 2):

`gnome-system-tools` is the package provides all this information. This package is a Cross-platform configuration utilities.

Date & Time related are included in `gnome-time-admin`

Check here for package details: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/gnome-time-admin

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I meant that neither ntp nor openntpd seem to be installed and somehow the clock is synchronized. But I don't know how. Shouldn't there be a *background process/daemon* running?

Comment: @medigeek: Should. But it could also call `ntpdate` repeatedly.